# How to autostart an application in GDM3?

Tags: gdm

GDM3 version `3.28.2-4`.

Is there a directory or configuration option for programs that GDM3 executes when login screen appears?

---

In my current setup the auto-login shell command is run from `rc.local`:

```
 sh -c "sleep 30; echo -n 1 >/dev/autologin" &
```

The 30-second delay is taken from experience, but it is random and uncertain. What I would like to do is to run `echo -n 1 >/dev/autologin` *exactly* when login screen appears.

---

`/dev/autologin` is "arduino pro micro" which enters user password via keyboard when it receives a signal via TTY. The following sketch is used:

```
void setup()
{
  TXLED0;
}

void loop()
{
  while (Serial.read() == -1) ;

  Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.release(KEY_RETURN);

  delay(1000);

  Keyboard.press('1');
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.release('1');

  delay(1000);

  Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.release(KEY_RETURN);
}
```

(Also note that for this to work, udev rule must be added to create `/dev/autologin` and probing by ModemManager must be disabled for this device.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en

> 5.2. Autostart Configuration
>   The /gdm/autostart/LoginWindow directory contains files in the format specified by the "FreeDesktop.org Desktop Application Autostart Specification". Standard features in the specification may be used to specify programs that should auto-restart or only be launched if a GConf configuration value is set, etc.
>
> Any .desktop files in this directory will cause the associated program to automatically start with the login GUI greeter. By default, GDM is shipped with files which will autostart the gdm-simple-greeter login GUI greeter itself, the gnome-power-manager application, the gnome-settings-daemon, and the metacity window manager. These programs are needed for the greeter program to work. In addition, desktop files are provided for starting various AT programs if the configuration values specified in the Accessibility Configuration section below are set.